# The "Using Multiple Delegates" developer.apple.com example

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch

I want to use the section "[Using Multiple Delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingMultipleDelegates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002267-BAJJDECB)" for xml parsing. But the example the article provides is only a snippet of it.

I have found another guy who wants to do the same http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/55427-parsing-repeating-nested-xml-nsxmlparser.html

But he doesn't get any answers. Maybe some one in here have examples?

(I have created a "similar" post some days ago, but the answer I got was still just using the normal NSXMLParser)

Comment: What are your problems with it? I find it quite clear.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some XML you are trying to parse using this strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this XML:

```
<Person>
    <Name>Joe Doe</Name>
    <Adress>
        <Street>A Street</Street>
        <City>A City</City>
    </Adress>
    <Job>
        <Company>A Company</Company>
        <Position>Job title</Position>
    </Job>
</Person>
```

Apple's article suggests that you will transform it into Objects. But each Class is also comforting the parser delegate protocol and knows how to parse its children.

The parser encounters the start of a Person tag, creates a person object and sets this object as the new delegate. Now the delegate methods implementations of person will be triggered. If now the Address tag is found, person creates a Address object. and sets this as delegate. and this object knows how to handle a address. and every time a end tag was found, the actual delegate set back the delegate to the object, that set it self as a delegate.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is very clear and it's exactly how I want to do it. But my problem is coding it. I'm trying right now :) thanks.